ubuntu 24.04 cannot see Nvidia GPU after I borked the graphics driver- 3070 card
I currently have Ubuntu 24.04. I had my GPU a 3070 Nvidia working fine on asus x299 Motherboard only a few hours ago, and it has been rnning fine for over a year. I did a nvidia sudo apt update and the display stopped working. I ended up purging my nvidia drivers (regretably), and can now only access my PC via SSH from another computer. I cannot remote in via any desk and monitor won’t work on 3070 HDMI, and my motherboard has no display port, so I am only on ssh.
I tried installing nvidia drivers via apt version 550. it installs. When I type :
anon@anon-System-Product-Name:~$ dkms status
nvidia/550.67, 6.5.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
sudo lshw -C display - I get nothing (it is as if it cannot see the GPU at all)
anon@anon-System-Product-Name:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
Any help would be appreciated. It was literally working 5 hours ago, i have not touched the PC at all, and now I have borked the drivers somehow.
Even if I purge all Nvidia drivers, I still cannot get a display up on my HDMI monitor or connect through Anydesk or anything. It is asif I have completely stuffed the default drivers too. I would be happy just to get some GUI so I can proceed with fault finding.
Any hep would be much appreciated. Shouldn't the system be able to see the GPU hardware? All the guides I see show the hardware even without the drivers, but for some reason I cannot see the GPU?
Thankyou
